# Pub Sub using http(port 80) ( NO WCF client)

Tags: wcf, networking

I want to develop a scalable pub-sub system
it has to be on port 80
firewalls \ NAT should just work
and I cannot deploy a WCF client ( server can be WCF if needed )
any thouhts \ suggestions on how to get going

Answer (score 0):

You could use MSMQ over HTTP. Check out [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/mismail/archive/2008/12/31/msmq-over-http.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Publish-Subscribe Framework and the Publish-Subscribe Example developed by Juval Lowy at [IDesign](http://www.idesign.net).  The framework and example can be downloaded and used for free.  You just have to provide your email address.  The download link is [here](http://www.idesign.net/idesign/DesktopDefault.aspx?tabindex=5&tabid=11#Operations).  You may have to scroll up just a little bit to see them both.